# DELETE request in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a categories page and create a remove button which to remove it the categories, the image as below: 
[image]

So the problem is show me '**MethodNotAllowedHttpException**'

Alright. Here is **Route** file

```
Route::delete('removeCategory/{id}','AdminController@removeCategory');
```

**Controller** file

```
 public function removeCategory(Request $id){
    $cats = cats::find($id);
    $cats->delete();

}
```

and **View** file

```
@foreach($data as $product)
  <tr  style="height:50px">
    <td style="padding:10px">{{$product->cat_name}}</td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-fill btn-primary"
           href="{{url('/admin/editCategory')}}/{{$product->id}}">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{url('admin/removeCategory')}}/{{$product->id}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
       class="btn btn-sm btn-fill btn-primary">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Thanks for anyone share the info to me, I have tried it but showing me this error message.
[image]

Comment: Don't forget to use `{!! method_field('delete') !!}`

Comment: Also, your onClick validation will always work, if JS is disabled, meaning, it will delete by default and not delete, if JS confirm works. If you want to make a validation, make sure that by default it doesn't work, and will work ONLY if you successfully validate request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since You want to do it without complicating the code with ajax,

solution is simply sending `POST` request and defining `DELETE` method as hidden field.

For simplicity You can add that field using [method_field helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-method-field):

```
@foreach($data as $product)
  <tr  style="height:50px">
    <td style="padding:10px">{{$product->cat_name}}</td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-fill btn-primary"
           href="{{url('/admin/editCategory')}}/{{$product->id}}">Edit</a></td>

    <td>
      <form 
        method="post" 
        action="{{url(''admin/removeCategory')}}/{{$product->id}}"> 

        {!! Form::token() !!}
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

        <button 
          type="submit"
          onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
          class="btn btn-sm btn-fill btn-primary">Remove</button>
      </form>
    </td>

  </tr>
@endforeach
```

and make sure after deleting object it's returning back to listing:

```
public function removeCategory($id) {
  $Cat = cats::find($id);
  if ($Cat) {
    $Cat->delete();
  }
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

---

**UPD.:** This answer may be a bit outdated and Form class may be removed from new versions of Laravel.
If you see: `Class "Form" not found` install `laravelcollective\html` package

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

or remove `Form::token()`

or replace with: `csrf_token` [described here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests)

Comment: Yup. I have tried the method you sharing to do it, but it still showing MethodNotAllowedHttpException error even I do it through a form.

Comment: thanks for everyone especially answer from num8er and Devon! :)

Comment: yes. Indeed. Is a correct answer and I vote for the acceptance answer so anyone those have same issue can be use as reference.

Comment: Getting error `Class "Form" not found`

Comment: @NinjaTurtle install it: `composer require laravelcollective/html`

Comment: @NinjaTurtle update my answer with 3 proposals

Answer (score 7):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` tells us that we tried to request the server with a http method type which is not supported at that endpoint. For example you tried to do a `GET` request on an url which only allows `DELETE`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Answer (score 3):

Try editing your route to this: 
`Route::get('removeCategory/{id}','AdminController@removeCategory');`

Then edit your controller to this:

```
public function removeCategory($id){
    $cats = cats::find($id);
    $cats->delete();
    return response(['Message' => 'This request has been deleted'], 200);
}
```

This is an alternative to the answer provided above, though I would recommend sticking to the answer provided by num8er.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must submit a DELETE request.  Look at num8er's answer for this.  You don't have to do it through a form, you can do it through AJAX, but just using `<a href` will result in a GET request.
2. You are also type hinting `$id` as a Request object in the controller method. 
   Therefore, Laravel will provide you with a Request object instead of the number passed as a parameter in the URL.   You need to remove the type hinting on that parameter, or use a type that actually fits:

---

```
 public function removeCategory($id) {

 }
```